# Holomorphicity of Functions of unitary matrices

Tags: gauge-theory, lattice-model, analyticity, lattice-gauge-theory

I am studying lattice QCD and there I encounter functions of unitary matrices. For ex. The action, $S = \sum$Tr( plaquettes), where each plaquette, $P$ is written as,
$$ P = U_{\mu}(x)U_{\nu}(x+\mu){U}_{\mu}^\dagger(x+\nu){U}_{\nu}^\dagger(x) $$
here $\mu$, $\nu$ represent directions and $x$ represents lattice sites.
While going over the literature [1], i encounter terms like holomorphicity of these functions of unitary matrices which I am unable to make any sense of.
If anyone can help me understand how to check if a given function $f(U)$ (where $U$ is a unitary matrix) is holomorphic or not, or can direct me to the topic i need to study for this. It would be a great help.\

References:

1. So for example https://arxiv.org/abs/1808.04400 here in equation (14) they propose a function, $f(U)$ and in paragraph below mention this function is not holomorphic.

Answer (score 1):

The set of matrices is a complex manifold, i.e. locally described by $\mathbb{C}^n$. [Therefore one needs to check what holomorphicity means on $\mathbb{C}^n$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_of_several_complex_variables). Indeed, consider a function $f:\mathbb{C}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{C}^m$ and pick a point $z_0 \in \mathbb{C}^n$. Then $f$ is complex differentiable at $z_0$ if there is a a linear map $L_z : \mathbb{C}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{C}^m$ continuous at $z_0$ such that

$$ f(z) = f(z_0) + L_z(z-z_0)  \ . $$

Then $L_{z_0}$ is the derivative of $f$ at $L_{z_0}$.
The important part is of course the absence of $\overline{z} - \overline{z}_0$.

In the paper you gave, they enlarge their gauge group from the unitary group to the special linear group. The function they define depends on expressions of the form $UU^\dagger$. This is not holomorphic on the special linear group, but it is holomorphic on the unitary group. Indeed, in the unitary group we can replace daggers, that is, complex conjugations, by taking the inverse, which is holomorphic. That is the reason why the action, which is of the form $U_1U_2U_3^\dagger U_4^\dagger = U_1U_2U_3^{-1}U_4^{-1}$ is holomorphic on the unitary matrices, but not the special linear transformations.

Comment: Thanks for an answer. I understand it a little better now. But I have a doubt based on your argument, that even the action S = $\sum$(plaquette) has combinations like $U_1 U_2 U_3^\dagger U_4^\dagger$. But I don't this Action should be non-holomorphic in this case (qcd-lat).

Comment: i read a bit more in detail, and the important thing i was missing before is that $U_1U_2^\dagger$ is holomorphic on the unitary group, but not the special linear group.

Comment: can you point me to the references, that would be helpful

Comment: what references are you looking for?

Comment: references from where I can learn about how $U_1U_2^\dagger$ is holomorphic

Comment: Are you interested in definition of holomorphicity on complex manifolds? In the wikipedia page i linked there is some section to this. I think from there one can see that $U_1 U_2^\dagger = U_1U_2^{-1}$ is holomorphic on the unitary group. Maybe a simple case, like $U(2)$ is insightful: parametrize in terms of complex parameters, and convince yourself that it is holomorphic in the usual sense.